# Create templates overloading friend operators in template class

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, operator-keyword

I really don't know how to create this properly. I have templates class with overloads for operators. And as i know i need to create templates to overload this operators for more universal form. My problem is that code not compile and i don't know how to fix it
**Example:**

```
    NSize<30> a(101);
    NSize<25> b(120);
    NSize<30> c(115);
    NSize<30> res = (a*b)*(a*c)*(c*b)*(b*a)*(a*c);
```

In the end, I should be able to do it. For now i defined it as :

```
template <int length>
friend NSize  operator * (const NSize &a, const NSize &b){
   //sth
}
```

And definition of my class looks like this:

```
template<int size,typename basic_type=unsigned int,typename long_type=unsigned long long,long_type base=256>
class NSize
{
   public:
   //sth
}
```

Comment: What compile error do you get?

Comment: error: no match for 'operator*' (operand types are 'NSize<30>' and 'NSize25>')  NSize<30> res = (a*b)*(a*c)*(c*b)*(b*a)*(a*c);

Comment: Does `NSzie<25>*NSize<30>` make sense? How multiplication works here?

Comment: @lol4t0 Yes,it does. As I understand, 25 and 30 it's just how many digits class can store. 
Thus, you can multiplicate `Nsize<25>*NSize<30>`, but you'll get `Nsize<55>`
or more

Comment: Yea, as above.  And in case of + ,when size not big enough it'll be filled by zeros . But not in logic of this is my problem...

Comment: Why is the `operator*` a function template?

Comment: Because i need to create universal version for NSize with different sizes. It's not my idea, i have to do this this way...

Comment: Well it's not difficult to make it compilable but what to do with the size? Actually result of `Nsize<25> * Nsize<30>` could be `NSize<55>` but that is like gross

Comment: If it's a template, then you will have to call it like so: `(a.operator*<length>(b)).operator*<length>((a.operator*<length>(c)))`. Doesn't seem like a very good idea.

Comment: I know ! But that is my assignment, I can't argue with a teacher in this case. It's just to show us how complicated things we can do with templates...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement your `operator*` the following way:

```
template<int size,typename basic_type=unsigned int,typename long_type=unsigned long long,long_type base=256>
class NSize
{
    // Note: that is not member but just friend
    template <int lengthA, int lengthB>
    friend NSize<lengthA + lengthB>  operator * (const NSize<lengthA> &a, const NSize<lengthB> &b);
};

// Actual definition that will work for every pair of Nsize of arbitrary size
template <int lengthA, int lengthB>
NSize<lengthA + lengthB>  operator * (const NSize<lengthA> &a, const NSize<lengthB> &b)
{
    return NSize<lengthA + lengthB>(...);
}
```

The idea is that we should define `opeator *` the way it could take 2 `Nsize` of arbitrary size. Then it generates the result with the size being the sum of argument sizes (to be sure result always fits)

However using this approach this code

```
int main() {
    NSize<30> a(101);
    NSize<25> b(120);
    NSize<30> c(115);
    auto res = (a*b)*(a*c)*(c*b)*(b*a)*(a*c);
}
```

will end up with `res` size being 285

<kbd>[Live example](http://ideone.com/bAyUCt)</kbd>

If you want to stick to the bigger argument size you can replace sum with maximum:

```
constexpr int constmax(int a, int b) {
    return a>b?a:b;
}

//.....

friend NSize<constmax(lengthA,lengthB)>  operator * (const NSize<lengthA> &a, const NSize<lengthB> &b);
```

<kbd>[Live example](http://ideone.com/lmvwyu)</kbd>

Comment: I've tried this before i asked, and this created the same error as i wrote .

Comment: (1) I also tried it before posting and (2) you din't wrote any error message

Comment: Sorry, it was in comments. error: no match for 'operator*' (operand types are 'NSize<30>' and 'NSize25>') NSize<30> res = (ab)*(ac)*(cb)*(ba)*(a*c); 
[EDIT:]
It cant be sum of lengths, it's need to be as i wrote in example.

Comment: @Yurrili, it can't be as you wrote, it can be only sum of length. `5*5=25` and `length(5) + length(5) == length(25)`. Think about it

Comment: You don't understand. The size of the number always will be much bigger than number, just because, and if not, i need to throw exceptions. And it's not about logic here. I perfectly know that you completely right about size, i know but as i wrote before it's my assignment. I have to stick to the rules, okay ? 
[EDIT} But thanks for the help, I'll accept your answer, and just ask a teacher. It'll be the easier way.

Comment: @Yurrili, ok may be it is reasonable approach. I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Make `operator*` non-template, because why should it be a template.

Otherwise you would have to explicitly specify the undeducible template parameter `length` every time you want to call the `operator*`, like so:

```
a.operator*<length>(b)
```

instead of

```
a * b
```

Comment: That you should write `a.operator*<length>(b)` instead of `a*b`.

Comment: Well, how else are you going to specify the template argument? `a*<length>b` doesn't work.

Comment: Template arguments deduction!