# Create templates overloading operator in template class

Tags: c++, templates

Yesterday I saw one question here 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33487463/create-templates-overloading-friend-operators-in-template-class).

It has answer, however it doesn't work for me.

So, as in first question

```
 NSize<30, unsigned char, unsigned short> a(101);
 NSize<25, unsigned char, unsigned short> b(120);
 NSize<15, unsigned char, unsigned short> c(115);
 NSize<30> res = (a*b)*(a*c);
```

And template class

```
template<int size,typename basic_type=unsigned int,typename long_type=unsigned long long,long_type base=256>
class NSize
{
   ...
}
```

And solution from Lol4t0

```
template <int lengthA, int lengthB>
NSize<lengthA + lengthB>  operator * (const NSize<lengthA> &a, const NSize<lengthB> &b)
{
    return NSize<lengthA + lengthB>(...);
}
```

So, we have really big numbers. For them we have our class NSize in which `size` is how many digits we can store for this number.

Thus, for `NSize<3>`the biggest number that we can store it's 999.

And we want to have some operators overloaded for `NSize`. It's easy when `size` is similar, but when `size` is different we have problems.

`Lol4t0's` solution doesn't work for me, and that's what CLion returns me

```
error: 'NSize<max(aS, bS)> NSize<size, basic_type, long_type, base>::operator*(NSize<aS>&, NSize<bS>&)' must take either zero or one argument
     NSize<max(aS,bS)> operator * (NSize<aS> &a, NSize<bS> &b)

error: no match for 'operator*' (operand types are 'NSize<30, unsigned char, short unsigned int>' and 'NSize<30, unsigned char, short unsigned int>')
     NSize<30, unsigned char, unsigned short> resc = (a*b)*(a*c);
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Is this the actual code? It looks that you are using non-const references

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki
Yes, had const Nsize there, but changed it when I was trying to make program work.

Comment: Please post your actual code, in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It looks as if you're trying to make your `operator*` a member function, in which case it should take a single argument (which is what your compiler is telling you).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not that easy to figure out the problem without a compilable example, but to me the it seems to be the following: You overload your multiplication operator is defined only for the default template parameters. That is, the code

```
template <int lengthA, int lengthB>
NSize<lengthA + lengthB>  operator * (const NSize<lengthA> &a, const NSize<lengthB> &b)
{
    return NSize<lengthA + lengthB>(...);
}
```

corresponds to

```
template <int lengthA, int lengthB>
NSize<lengthA + lengthB, unsigned int, unsigned long long, 256>  operator * 
(const NSize<lengthA, unsigned int, unsigned long long, 256> &a, const NSize<lengthB, unsigned int, unsigned long long, 256> &b)
{
    return NSize<lengthA + lengthB, unsigned int, unsigned long long, 256>(...);
}
```

But next, you call it with two classes of type

```
NSize<some_integer, unsigned char,       unsigned short>
                  //^^^^^^^^^^^^         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                  //not: unsigned int    not: unsigned long long
```

**The solution is simple**: spell out all relevant template parameters in your `operator*` definition, which gives you a detailed control on the returned parameter types.

If you find yourself doing that all the time you might prefer using a `std::common_type`-like helper class,

```
template<typename T, typename S>
struct common_type
{
    using type = typename std::common_type<T, S>::type;
};

template<int size1, typename basic_type1 /*, ... */
       , int size2, typename basic_type2 /*, .. */>
struct common_type<NSize<size1, basic_type1 /*, ... */>
                 , NSize<size2, basic_type2 /*, ... */> >
{
    using type = NSize<size1+size2, typename std::common_type<basic_type1,basic_type2>::type /*, ... */ >;
};
```

and return that as result of your multiplication operator:

```
template<typename ... Args1, typename ... Args2>
auto operator*(Nsize<Args1 ...> const& nsize1, Nsize<Args2 ...> const& nsize2)
    -> typename common_type<Nsize<Args1 ...>, Nsize<Args2 ...> >::type
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: Yeah sure I missed that part :)